EFCore ToJson() - camelCasing
I have an existing column in MsSQL which is just a string but in json format. Here's and example (real one is much more complex):
{
  "template": {
    "dateOfBirth": "Random Date of Birth",
    "footer": "Random Footer",
    "fullName": "Random Full Name",
    "linkedInUrl": "Random LinkedIn URL",
    "location": "Random Location",
    "nickname": "Random Nickname",
    "profileText": "Random Profile Text",
    "shortExpertises": [
      "Random Expertise"
    ],
  }
}

Now I'm trying to add the new ToJson() in ef core.
OLD
public string ProfileJson { get; set; }

NEW
public Profile ProfileJson { get; set; }

builder
     .OwnsOne(x => x.ProfileJson)
     .ToJson();

But the problem is they are always null. Because the existing casing are camelCasing and EF Core expects PascalCasing.
Is there a way to make EF Core use PascalCasing? I've searched the Docs and github - no dice.

What does the Profile class look like?

This should help: https://www.koskila.net/how-to-serialize-to-json-in-camelcase-using-net-core/
